# window.close is not working

Tags: javascript, c#

Window.close  is not working.I couldn't understand. Please help me to understand this problem.

Here is my Javascript:

```
function CloseWindow(message) {
  alert(message);
  window.close();
}
```

Code Behind in c#:

```
_message = "Request has been accpeted successfully.";
myScript = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>CloseWindow('" + _message + "');</script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "myscript", myScript);
```

Comment: Due to security reasons, I dont think you will be able to close the window via JavaScript _unless that window instance is created by you_

Comment: You can only close windows that you've opened

Comment: Why  it's not working? Is there any wrong code?

Comment: make sure that CloseWindow exists further up the DOM than the script that executes it.

If the CloseWindow function doesn't exist on the page yet - it'll throw an error.

Comment: @user3510330 Two people gave you a perfect explanation. Didn't you understand?

Comment: Well, I never use this function, if I knew more behind it I could myself explain it at short time. I never needed to do this

Comment: How about posting the code of window creation too!

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack to close the window.

```
window.opener = null;
window.open('', '_self');
window.close()
```

But it does not work in `chrome` nor `firefox`.